# Automatic DataGrid binding based on search condition

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

My XAML file:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[track]}"  SelectionChanged="LoadAlbumDetails" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[artist_name].Value}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Album" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[album_name].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[duration].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[price].Value}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<albums>
    <track>
        <id>211</id>
        <name>If you say something..</name>
        <duration>156</duration>
        <artist_id>13</artist_id>
        <artist_name>Richard Keating</artist_name>
        <album_id>29</album_id>
        <album_name>Don't say anything..</album_name>
        <price>$10</price>
   </track>

   <track>
        <id>212</id>
        <name>My heart is a stereo</name>
        <duration>150</duration>
        <artist_id>14</artist_id>
        <artist_name>Maroon 5</artist_name>
        <album_id>30</album_id>
        <album_name>Maroon 5 stereo</album_name>
        <price>$15</price>
   </track>
</albums>
```

in my .xaml.cs

//For initial loading for the XML to be bound to the datagrid

```
  protected void LoadAlbumDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
            IList rows = LibraryView.SelectedItems;
            XElement row = (XElement)rows[0];
            //MessageBox.Show(row.Element("album_name").Value.ToString());

   }

//Search button
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    //Am trying to use the concept of DataSet.Select or DataTable.Select

 }
```

When i type Maroon 5 in text box and click search button , i want to use something like

```
DataSet.Select("columnName1 like 'Maroon 5'");
```

and then rebind the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter the datagrid using CollectionView, a tutorial is [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html).

```
private CollectionView _collectionView;

public IList Tracks { get; set; } // your itemssource
public string FilterString { get; set; } // bind to your search textbox

private void Init() // call this when you first init your datagrid
{
   _collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tracks);
   _collectionView.Filter = TrackFilter;
}
private bool TrackFilter(object item)
{
   return track.columnName1.Contains( _filterString );
}
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _collectionView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stafford, that is a good article, i need to use it, but i don't know how to bind XML to a datagrid , how do i pin out XML to class as done in the link?